# Analyzing logical form of the statement

Tags: logic

Statement as follows:

> If anyone in the dorm has a friend who has the measles, then everyone
>   in the dorm will have to be quarantined.

My attempt:

1. $D(x) - x$ lives in the dorm
2. $M(x) - x$ has measles
3. $F(x,y) - y$ is friend of $x$
4. $Q(x) - x$ is quarantined

$$ \exists y \bigl(D(y) \land F(y,x) \land M(x)\bigr) \rightarrow \forall p\bigl(D(p) \rightarrow Q(p)\bigr)$$

Is it correct? Any suggestions for improvement will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare $x$ too, not only $y$. That's the only mistake, so the correct form is similar

$\exists y \exists x\bigl(D(y) \land F(y,x) \land M(x)\bigr) \rightarrow \forall p\bigl(D(p) \rightarrow Q(p)\bigr)$.